# What is the difference between visit and current_path and use of .should in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, capybara, rspec-rails

```
Then /^I should be on the free signup page$/ do
  *current_path.should == free_signup_path* 
end

Then /^I should be on the free signup page$/ do
   *visit free_signup_path* 
end
```

What is the difference between these two ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#visit` tells the browser to go to a new url and will initiate a get request to the app being tested. `#current_path` lets you read the current location the browser is at.

Note: you should stop using `current_path.should == some_path`, when verifying the current path, and instead use `page.should have_current_path(some_path)`.  The have_current_path matcher includes waiting behavior and will help make tests less flaky with JS capable drivers

Comment: Thanks Tom for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You use `visit` to tell rspec to go to that path to validate if something works or is present. For example:

```
it 'contains the new sessions form' do
    visit 'sessions/new'
    current_path.should have_content("Sign In")
end
```

Granted that my sign in form has a button or whatever with the text 'sign in' this test will pass.

You generally have to declare what path the test hould go to in order to detect content.

Hope this helps!